# Error setting up Kubernetes with Vagrant

Tags: kubernetes

When I run the Kubernetes vagrant setup script:

```
export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=vagrant
curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash
```

I get:

```
Validating master
Validating minion-1

Waiting for each minion to be registered with cloud provider
error: couldn't read version from server: Get https://10.245.1.2/api:dial tcp 10.245.1.2:443: connection refused
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Same thing here, it might be that something is broken with current script version (I've tried just a few minutes ago)

Comment: I tried to do it with Google Compute Engine but I get a similar error, so frustrating :/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like issue is gone, I've tried one more time and installation went flawlessly:

[image]